# Click triggering anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anybody see why this triggers when I click anywhere on the page, and not just the specified element?

```
var ab = function() {
    alert('sup');
}
$(document).on('click', $('.ac'), ab );
```

Comment: The delegated version of on() does not accept a jQuery object as it's second argument, only strings should be used for the selector.

Answer (score 2):

**Wrong JQuery** :Change your code and try

```
 $(document).on('click',  '.ac', ab ){

 // do some thing 
};
```

As @Adeno mentioned in existing comment *on() does not accept a jQuery object as it's second argument, only strings should be used for the selector.*